# ¿Como puedo reiniciar nuevamente una tabla de mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, tablas

Resulta que quiero que mi tabla de base de datos inicialize nuevamente el id autoincrementable en 1 , hacer un reset básicamente de la tabla sin tener que eliminar esa tabla y crearla nuevamente para que cuente nuevamente en 1 , de antemano Muchas gracias!! Adjunto imágen de la tabla a modo de ejemplo :

[image: idMunicipalidad Empieza en 91 ,pero quiero que nuevamente sea 1 sin necesidad de eliminar la tabla y crearla nuevamente]

Comment: Después de truncar la tabla ejecuta: `ALTER TABLE \`nombre_tabla\` MODIFY \`columna_id\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;`

Comment: Gracias!! Me funciono!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en MySQL hay un metodo para vaciar una tabla completa. El metodo Truncate

*TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;*

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me funciono!!

Comment: @LuisCifuentes, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada.